# Linq - filtros entre datas

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho um método o qual devolve uns registos da base de dados filtrados entre datas, estando construído da seguinte forma:

```
public List<ProcessosInformacoesAnexos_Model> DevolveTodosAnexos(DateTime dataInicial, DateTime dataFinal, int pagina, int numeroRegistos, out int totalRegistos)
        {
            var query = from t1 in baseDados.tbProcessos_Informacoes_Anexos
                        select t1;

            //Data
            if(dataInicial!= DateTime.MinValue && dataFinal!=DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                var dataInicial2 = DateTime.Parse(dataInicial.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
            var dataFinal2 = DateTime.Parse(dataFinal.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
                query = query.Where(x => x.tbProcessos.DataCriacao >= dataInicial2 && x.tbProcessos.DataCriacao <= dataFinal2);
            }

            totalRegistos = query.Count();
            pagina--;
            var listaProcesso = query.OrderByDescending(x=>x.DataCriacao).Skip(pagina * numeroRegistos).Take(numeroRegistos).ToList(); 

            var resultado = (from tbProcessosAnexos in listaProcesso
                            select new ProcessosInformacoesAnexos_Model()
                            {
                                Id = tbProcessosAnexos.Id,
                                ProcessoId = tbProcessosAnexos.ProcessoId,
                                IdProcessoInformacao = tbProcessosAnexos.IdProcessoInformacao,
                                Ficheiro = tbProcessosAnexos.Ficheiro,
                                IdTipoAnexo = tbProcessosAnexos.IdTipoAnexo,
                                Designacao = tbProcessosAnexos.Designacao,
                                Descricao = tbProcessosAnexos.Descricao,
                                UtilizadorCriacao = tbProcessosAnexos.UtilizadorCriacao,
                                DataCriacao = tbProcessosAnexos.DataCriacao,
                            }).ToList();

            return resultado;
        }
```

O problema ocorre quando aplico os filtros na expressão em linq dentro do if onde, ao pegar na query que é construída, ele coloca as datas da seguinte forma: @p__linq__0 e @p__linq__1, em baixo tem a query que resulta do linq.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[ProcessoId] AS [ProcessoId], 
    [Extent1].[IdProcessoInformacao] AS [IdProcessoInformacao], 
    [Extent1].[Ficheiro] AS [Ficheiro], 
    [Extent1].[IdTipoAnexo] AS [IdTipoAnexo], 
    [Extent1].[Designacao] AS [Designacao], 
    [Extent1].[Descricao] AS [Descricao], 
    [Extent1].[Custos] AS [Custos], 
    [Extent1].[CustosValor] AS [CustosValor], 
    [Extent1].[CustosFicheiro] AS [CustosFicheiro], 
    [Extent1].[CustosData] AS [CustosData], 
    [Extent1].[Pago] AS [Pago], 
    [Extent1].[PagoDocumento] AS [PagoDocumento], 
    [Extent1].[PagoData] AS [PagoData], 
    [Extent1].[IdMotivoRecibo] AS [IdMotivoRecibo], 
    [Extent1].[Ordem] AS [Ordem],
    [Extent1].[UtilizadorCriacao] AS [UtilizadorCriacao], 
    [Extent1].[DataCriacao] AS [DataCriacao]
    FROM  [dbo].[tbProcessos_Informacoes_Anexos] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbProcessos] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProcessoId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Custos] = 1) AND ([Extent2].[DataCriacao] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[DataCriacao] <= @p__linq__1)
```

Alguém sabe o que poderá ser?

EDIT:
Afinal consegui descobrir uma forma, quer era colocar esse filtro entre datas logo quando instancio a query:

```
var query = from t1 in baseDados.tbProcessos_Informacoes_Anexos
                        where (t1.DataCriacao>= dataInicial && t1.DataCriacao <= dataFinal)
                        select t1;
```

Era preciso colocar um "Where", mas não entendo bem o porquê :/

Comment: pq pegar a data, converter para string, e depois chamar o Parse convertendo pra DateTime de novo ? E qual o problema com a query ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis eu faço isso porque ela vem de um formato diferente (dd-mm-aaaa) da view, por isso tive que colocar nesse formato :/

Comment: está vindo como `DateTime`, não importa o formato

Answer (score 1):

Araujo.

Isso ocorre pelo fato de que o c# impede o ataque de SQLInjection, onde os dados que viram de fora, no caso passados pelo usuário, podem ser maliciosos e para assegurar de que isso não ocorra, ele criar essas variáveis, onde encontra estes paramentos.

Para poder usar esta query em um SGBD você precisa declarar estas variáveis e setar elas com os valores correspondentes para pesquisa. No código rodado pelo c# ele mesmo se encarrega desta tarefa, porém quando obtemos a query gerada e queremos usa-la precisamos declara-la acima e então setar seus valores.

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 datetime
DECLARE @p__linq__1 datetime

SET @p__linq__0 = '2019-05-02'
SET @p__linq__1 = '2019-08-09'

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[ProcessoId] AS [ProcessoId], 
    [Extent1].[IdProcessoInformacao] AS [IdProcessoInformacao], 
    [Extent1].[Ficheiro] AS [Ficheiro], 
    [Extent1].[IdTipoAnexo] AS [IdTipoAnexo], 
    [Extent1].[Designacao] AS [Designacao], 
    [Extent1].[Descricao] AS [Descricao], 
    [Extent1].[Custos] AS [Custos], 
    [Extent1].[CustosValor] AS [CustosValor], 
    [Extent1].[CustosFicheiro] AS [CustosFicheiro], 
    [Extent1].[CustosData] AS [CustosData], 
    [Extent1].[Pago] AS [Pago], 
    [Extent1].[PagoDocumento] AS [PagoDocumento], 
    [Extent1].[PagoData] AS [PagoData], 
    [Extent1].[IdMotivoRecibo] AS [IdMotivoRecibo], 
    [Extent1].[Ordem] AS [Ordem],
    [Extent1].[UtilizadorCriacao] AS [UtilizadorCriacao], 
    [Extent1].[DataCriacao] AS [DataCriacao]
    FROM  [dbo].[tbProcessos_Informacoes_Anexos] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbProcessos] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProcessoId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Custos] = 1) AND ([Extent2].[DataCriacao] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[DataCriacao] <= @p__linq__1)
```

Desta forma você seta essas variáveis e ele passa a usar estes valores na consulta.

Comment: Agora entendo o porquê de ele criar isso :)
O problema a seguir é que ele nem chega a filtrar por datas, o que faz com que traga todos os registos na mesma :/

Comment: Tive um problema parecido, no meu caso era porque as datas no banco estavam sem hora, e eu passava um uma data com a hora atual, quando peguei apenas o valor com data sem a hora, ele conseguiu fazer o filtro. Não se é seu caso mais vale dar uma olhada.